# I want 10 numbers between RFMIn and RFMax with using linspace in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

**I am reading csv file and in that csv file have a Columns

RFMin and  RFMax**

```
1000     3333  
5125.5    5888
```

**I want 10 numbers between RFMIn and RFMax with using linspace in python**

```
import pandas as pd
Import numpy as np

df = csv.read_csv(filePath)
RFRange = np.linspace(RFMIn, RFMax, 10)
RFRange = RFRange.flatten()
RFarray=[]
for i in RFRange:
       RFarray.append(i)
dict = {‘RFRange’: RFarray}
data = pd.DataFrame(dict)
data.to_csv(‘Output.csv’, header=True, sep=’\t’)
```

**I want something like this:**

```
 1000
 1259.22
 1518.44
 1777.67
……..
…….
 3333
5125.5
5210.22
5294.94
……..
…….
5888
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is coming from the call to flatten. The flatten function of matplotlib converts a 2d array into a 1d array. However this is done in row-major order by default (https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html).

```
In [1]: a = [1000,5125.5]

In [2]: b = [3333,5888]

In [3]: import numpy as np

In [4]: np.linspace(a,b,10)
Out[4]: 
array([[1000.        , 5125.5       ],
       [1259.22222222, 5210.22222222],
       [1518.44444444, 5294.94444444],
       [1777.66666667, 5379.66666667],
       [2036.88888889, 5464.38888889],
       [2296.11111111, 5549.11111111],
       [2555.33333333, 5633.83333333],
       [2814.55555556, 5718.55555556],
       [3073.77777778, 5803.27777778],
       [3333.        , 5888.        ]])

In [5]: np.linspace(a,b,10).flatten()
Out[5]: 
array([1000.        , 5125.5       , 1259.22222222, 5210.22222222,
       1518.44444444, 5294.94444444, 1777.66666667, 5379.66666667,
       2036.88888889, 5464.38888889, 2296.11111111, 5549.11111111,
       2555.33333333, 5633.83333333, 2814.55555556, 5718.55555556,
       3073.77777778, 5803.27777778, 3333.        , 5888.        ])
```

As you can see this means that it converts your data into a different format to what you are expecting.

There are a few ways to change the order.
1) As per https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html you can use fortran ordering (column-major) when flattening

2) You can transpose your data before flattening
`RFRange = RFRange.T.flatten()` / `RFRange = RFRange.transpose().flatten()`

3) You can add a second loop when appending and append directly from the 2D array
I would suggest that this method is to be avoided though. It is ok for 10 points, however large loops can be quite slow in python and it is therefore better to use python built in functions where possible. For example in this case a numpy1d array can easily be converted to a list with the following command:
`RFArray = list(RFRange)`

Answer (score 0):

You want the array in ascending order? If it is, just do RFarray.sort()